# Delineating Agricultural Ditches in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to delineate agricultural ditches as part of my Wetland restoration suitability index, and I am having a hard time doing so. Calculating flow accumulation then creating channels is OK but it also picks up on natural features which I do not want.

As you can see in the attached image, the ditches are very visible from the hillshade, so surely there is a way I can somehow extract ditch polylines from this?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to find open source data of the natural waters and use to filter the result, or modify the DEM?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to start with what defines a ditch.  Saying you can plainly see it in this picture won't give you the language necessary for accomplishing your task.

What identifies a ditch from the computer's perspective?  i.e. a narrow elevation change over a long distance that's in a straight(ish) line.

- how narrow?
- how much of an elevation change?
- how long a distance?
- how straight? (deviation over distance in meters for example)

You should have these answers, then ask the question again.